Check if map has been touched (not taped) in flutter
Is there a way to check if the GoogleMap has been touched in Flutter?
There is onTap with GoogleMap, but it does not work since you have to tap the map.
I would like to respond if the map has been merely touched.
    GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: sub.read(),
                markers: ref.watch(mapMarkersProvider),
                zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                onMapCreated: (controller) {
                  ref
                      .read(currentMapControllerProvider.notifier)
                      .updateController(controller);
                },
                onTap: (_) {
                  _onMapTouch(true);
                }),

